# when can i omit the subject in comparative sentences

Tags: grammar, comparatives

I recently encountered two sentences -

1. Cars made in Japan are better than those made in Korea.

   - here, "those" cannot be omitted
2. Prices of mangos in Thailand are much lower than (those) in England.

   - here, "those" can be omitted

Can anyone please help why in the 1st sentence "those" cannot be omitted but can be omitted in the 2nd sentence? They look like having the same structure to me.

Thank you!
VC

Comment: You should match the title of your question to its body as they are not related. Comparatives involving (in)equality (as…as)  are not necessarily treated in all cases as  are comparatives for inferiority or superiority (than).

Comment: thank you. edited.

Comment: Your second sentence should read:  “The price of mangoes is lower in Thailand than in England”.